# How to set two environment variables and then run Php-cgi?

Tags: php, windows, cmd, command-line, cgi

I need to call a php-cgi after I have passed environmental variables to it.
These are the environmental variables.

```
REDIRECT_STATUS=true REQUEST_METHOD=GET program name
```

But it keeps giving me this response:

```
'REDIRECT_STATUS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I am using Windows 10. Does anyone know how this can be replicated in cmd.

Comment: Are you sure you're running this in bash? That error looks like something that would be produced by `CMD.EXE`.

Comment: @ghoti, I ran it both in cmd.exe and power shell, it replies with the same heartbreaking statements

Comment: That would be the problem, then. The notation you're using is for bash, not for CMD or Powershell. Please include more detail in your question -- exactly where you're running the command, how it relates to bash, etc. As it stands, there isn't enough information here to provide you with an answer.

Comment: @ghoti, all I want to do is get it run on windows 10. I don't care whether its bash or something else. By the way it was copied from a tutorial, so many years ago

Comment: Copied from a bash tutorial no doubt. I'm surprised that you don't care what you're running. It's a pity that you're here for a quick fix rather than to learn something. If you want help with one platform or another, then pick a platform and update your question appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three command lines needed to define the two environment variables and next run the program in Windows command line environment:

```
set "REDIRECT_STATUS=true"
set "REQUEST_METHOD=GET"
"program name"
```

The command to set an environment variable is **SET**. Run in a command prompt window `set /?` for help on this command.

It is also possible to run all three commands on one command line using operator `&`.

```
set "REDIRECT_STATUS=true" & set "REQUEST_METHOD=GET" & "program name"
```