# How do you compile Go program on Windows for MacOS

Tags: go

All the examples I've found so far assume you are using a Mac and compile for the other platforms.

Comment: why don't just do the same: set `GOOS` and `GOARCH` to the desired platform

Answer (score 2):

As stated you can set the GOOS and GOARCH.

you can check all the distro using the following go command

```
go tool dist list
```

How to build the application for MacOS

```
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=amd64 go build main.go
```

Comment: That notation (`GOOS=darwin ...`) is for bash (and some other shells) but not windows (CMD/powershell) which is the focus of this question. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50080193/11810946) describes a way of setting variables and running a program in one line on windows.

Comment: yes, that was it